# Adding a hidden input field to all the forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Is there a way to add a hidden input field to all the form that are declared in views in rails. The hidden field needs to have a value passed by a public property in the controller. Essentially I want any form that is given as response by the web server to have an additional hidden input element.

How I do this? Can I override the form_for by some means ? Or can I go with a wrapper of form in partials and enforce everybody to use the partial?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: OK, my first pass on this didn't work because you can't define a value in an initializer that you're later going to pass in from a controller. So you can go about this one of two ways.
You can define a `CustomFormBuilder` class - put it in an initializer -

```
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder 
  def submit(value, options = {})
    @template.hidden_field_tag(options.delete(:custom_param)) + super
  end
end
```

Then pass the `:builder` option to `form_for`

```
form_for @whatever, builder: CustomFormBuilder
```

and assuming you call `submit(value, options)` in the form, where options includes your custom_param, it will be overwritten by the custom method that inserts your hidden field with the value you want.

The alternative is to monkey patch monkey patch FormTagHelper instead:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper

  def extra_tags_for_form_with_custom_param(html_options)
    hidden_field_tag(html_options.delete('custom_param') +
    extra_tags_for_form_without_custom_param(html_options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :extra_tags_for_form, :custom_param
end
```

That's tweaking the code `form_for` uses to insert the authenticity token at the top of every form. Now you can pass that custom param to `form_for` after setting it as an instance variable in the controller:

```
form_for @object, custom_param: @custom_param do |f|
```

---

If you are using Ruby 2.0+ then you can use module prepend instead of the deprecated alias_method_chain e.g.

```
module CustomParamFormPatch
  private
  def extra_tags_for_form(html_options)
    hidden_field_tag(html_options.delete('custom_param')) +
    super
  end
end

ActionView::Base.prepend(CustomParamFormPatch)
```

Comment: I tried specifying the submit_Tag(value, options = {}) . It does not seem to render the hidden input element. I also added a log statement which did not seem to work. I have attached the builder rightly. My forms all use a submit_tag. Anything I'm missing out?

Comment: `submit_tag` isn't defined on the FormBuilder class, `submit` is. Since `submit_tag` is called on...actually I'm not sure what object those *_tag methods are called on, @template maybe - I don't think you can subclass it. You'd have to monkeypatch `submit_tag` within the FormTagHelper class, which feels more brittle to me. Any reason you're not just using `submit`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not a submit in the first place. I'm now converting it to submit. But is there a way I can access the current controller instance and get the property like in my case? I'm not finding a way to do that.

Comment: Set `@custom_param` as an instance variable in the controller.